# c# remove T and Z from datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, azure-data-factory

Net core application. I have Date Time field. I have an API which sends Date Time to Azure Data Factory. Whenever I see in ADF I see datetime as below

```
"StartDateTime": "2018-01-11T00:00:00Z", "EndDateTime": "2019-12-09T00:00:00Z"
```

My corresponding c# model looks like below

```
 public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
 public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
```

In ADF I see T and Z in datetime filed. I do not want this and I want something like this

2018-01-11 00:00:00.

Can someone help me to format datetime? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is "ADF"? Why do you care about the T and Z? It's important information in there. Is it causing a problem?

Comment: `DateTime` is essentially a `long` under the hood so it has nothing to do with how it is formatted as a string. The posted string representation corresponds to the ISO 8601 format, which can be parsed easily by `DateTime.Parse`. And when you need to display it as a string you use any [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) formatting you want.

Comment: What package do you use to send/serialize your model?

Comment: Hi David. ADF is azure Data Factory. In ADF I do not want T and Z.

Answer (score 1):

The text you're dealing with appears to be in the ISO 8601 standard format.

To parse that text into a `DateTime` you need something like this:

```
string text = "2018-01-11T00:00:00Z";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Ideally you'd use `DateTimeOffset` as this does a better job of handling the time zone.

```
DateTimeOffset dt = DateTimeOffset.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use appropriate format specifiers when printing DateTime

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-11T00:00:00Z");
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("G"));
```

This will print "1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM"
See here for format samples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_

*Note*: this actual output will be depended on your system date/time format preferences and current time zone. If this is not good for you, then you can explicitly specify format you want instead of "
G" from the sample. You can also perform appropriate timezone conversion if you need.

Comment: On my computer it prints `2018/01/11 10:30:00`. Now that's based on my time zone and preferences for dates and times. You need to be explicit about your time zone and preferences for why you print out `1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: Yes, important point, thank you. I updated the answer.